# How to attach blob index tags during a Azure Blob put request?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azureportal

I followed azure documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob for adding tags during the objects creation in azure blob. Its says that, we have to add 'x-ms-tags' in the request headers. The header that I am attaching to the PUT request is,

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': file.type,
  'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
  'x-ms-tags': 'tag1=value1'
}
```

But these tags are not getting added to the actual blobs. What am i missing here?

Also in the documentaion, it says that 'x-ms-tags' is "Supported in version 2019-12-12 and newer.". Which version they are mentioning here?

Edit1:

Code for uploading the file:

```
uploadToAzure = function (public_url, sas_token, file) {
  return $http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: public_url + '?' + sas_token,
    ignoreLoadingBar: true,
    data: file,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': file.type,
      'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
      'x-ms-tags': 'tag1=value1'
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    console.error("error", error)
    return error;
  });
}
```

Edit 2:

Edit 2:
Backend code for generating token:

GEM:

```
gem 'azure-storage-blob'
```

azure_blob_storage_initializer.rb

```
AZURE_SAS_TOKEN_GENERATOR = Azure::Storage::Common::Core::Auth::SharedAccessSignature.new(
  ENV['AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME'],
  ENV['AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY']
)
```

Generating token login:

```
SAS_TOKEN_OPTIONS = { service: 'b', resource: 'b' }.freeze
sas_token = AZURE_SAS_TOKEN_GENERATOR.generate_service_sas_token(blob_path, SAS_TOKEN_OPTIONS.merge(permissions: 'w'))
```

Comment: What's the kind of your Storage Account? Is it v1 or v2 or some other kind? Also, please share your complete code.

Comment: Its a StorageV2 account

Comment: Tags are supported on v2 account. Can you share your code?

Comment: @GauravMantri I have added the js code for uploading the blob

Comment: Aah...you're uploading using JS. Please check your SAS token. It should have something like `sv`. Can you tell what's the value for that?

Comment: oooh got it.. The sv value is "2017-11-09". I think this is why tags are not getting added.. What should i do to upgrade this?

Comment: You need to get a SAS token with signed version value greater than or equal to `2019-12-12`. Not sure how you're creating the SAS token but for this problem, you can create a SAS token using Azure Portal. That's supposed to use the latest version of REST API.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have added logic for generating the SAS token. How to get the SAS token specifying the version here?

Comment: Unfortunately using this gem won't work. According to the [changelog](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ruby/blob/master/common/ChangeLog.md), it only supports REST API version `2018-11-09` which does not have support for blob tags.

Comment: @GauravMantri What other ways to generate SAS token via code?

Comment: You can use SDKs for other languages like .Net, Java, Node etc. All of them support the latest version of Storage REST API.

Comment: No problem. I hope you’ll be able to solve the issue. Do post an answer once you’ve solved it. All the best!